# The new owner must have read permission - on custom lead conversion

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

I am actually having this error when converting a lead :

```
ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: TRANSFER_REQUIRES_READ
```

And in my code, I'm not changing the owner of the lead :

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(l.lead.Id);
//get the account id to use                 
lc.setAccountId(l.Acc);
//set status - compulsory
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
convertList.add(lc);

list<Database.LeadConvertResult> resultList = Database.convertLead(convertList);
```

And my code is running as an admin. And i'm trying to convert a lead as an admin.

Comment: Have you confirmed the lead owner has read access to Account, Contact and Opportunity?

Comment: Account is public read, Contact is private, and opportunity also is private. Im not using the standard opportunitybut a custom opportunity object. The owner of the lead is a marketing user, and for marketing users, we have sharing rules that allow them read/write access on all contacts. Do you think that the lead conversion process is trying to generate a standard opportunity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work. Thanks to @shailesh Deshpande comments, i got a clue about it. In fact by default it was generating an opportunity which we don't want. But the error occured when the owner of the lead is not an admin, even if the one converting the lead is an admin and that the code is running in as an admin. So to prevent generating the standard opportunity here is the code i added :

```
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
```

After this it works fine :)